# Error handling with verbose output

Tags: python, docopt

Im trying to implement the `--verbose` option in my script. The idea is to turn on extra printing of errors etc for debugging, but for some reason it doesnt seem to work. Ive tried a few variations of the `if verbose` statement but no joy. Im hoping someone could point me in the right direction?

**CLI EXAMPLE**

`./attack2.py -f wordfile.txt -d google.com --verbose 1`

**CLI OUTPUT**

```
unknown@ubuntu:~$ ./attack2.py -f wordfile.txt -d google.com --verbose 1
173.194.34.149
173.194.34.130
unknown@ubuntu:~$
```

**ARG PRINT**

```
{'--domain': 'google.com',
 '--file': 'wordfile.txt',
 '--help': False,
 '--thread': False,
 '--verbose': True,
 '10': False,
 '<1>': '1'}
```

**CODE**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
Description:

Basic Domain bruteforcer

Usage:
  attack2.py (-f <file>) (-d <domain>) [-t 10] [-v <1>]
  attack2.py -h | --help

Arguments:
  -f --file File to read potential Sub-domains from. (Required)
  -d --domain Domain to bruteforce. (Required)
Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  -p --proxy    Proxy address and port. [default: http://127.0.0.1:8080] (Optional)
  -t --thread   Thread count. (Optional)
  -v --verbose  Turn debug on. (Optional)
"""
import socket
from docopt import docopt


def fread(dwords):
        flist = open(dwords).readlines()
        return [s.replace('\n', '.') for s in flist]


def subcheck(subdomain, domain, verbose):

        vdomain = {}
        for sub in subdomain:
                try:
                        check = socket.gethostbyname(sub + domain)
                        vdomain[sub + domain] = check

                except socket.gaierror, e:
                        if verbose == True:
                                print arguments
                                print e, sub + domain
                        else:
                                pass
        return vdomain

if __name__ == "__main__":
        arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='0.1a')

        fread(arguments['--file'])
        returned_list = fread(arguments['--file'])
        returned_domains = subcheck(returned_list, arguments['--domain'], ['--verbose'])
```

Comment: Why not use http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse ?

Comment: Why don't you like to use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) and [logging](http://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) modules?

Comment: @agam360: because another answer about using `getopt` recommended `docopt` to the OP. Does it matter here?

Comment: Try to print the `type` of `verbose` variable `print type(verbose)` in function `subcheck`. IMO the type is `str` that's why it is not matching the condition.

Comment: to be fair im liking docopt :)

Comment: @anuragal its of type list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below line in function `subcheck`

```
returned_domains = subcheck(returned_list, arguments['--domain'], ['--verbose'])
```

should be

```
returned_domains = subcheck(returned_list, arguments['--domain'], arguments['--verbose'])
```

You forgot to pass the `verbose` param from arguments, instead you passed a `list`

Comment: ROFL u beet me too it by a few secs :)

Comment: As i worked it out myself is it bad practice to give myself the Correct answer?

Comment: @LearningCode - No obligation on you to set my answer as correct.

Comment: hmm i do feel obligated to set yourself correct, but im kinda proud i worked it out myself ^_^

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was calling the subcheck incorrectly.

Code should have looked like this

**Working CODE**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='0.1a')

        fread(arguments['--file'])
        returned_list = fread(arguments['--file'])
        returned_domains = subcheck(returned_list, arguments['--domain'], arguments['--verbose'])
        print returned_domains
```